# Android: unable to open database file

Tags: android, sqlite

When I tried to open a sqlite database, it caught exception :

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException : unable to open databse file.

My code is :

```
 final String  DATABASENAME   =    "MY_DB"; 
 SQLiteDatabase   objDb =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASENAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

### Edited

This is working fine android 2.2.
But it caught exception in android 2.1.

Please help me...
Thank you..

Comment: show your `DATABASENAME` value

Answer (score 2):

```
File sdcardfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(sdcardfile.getPath()
                                         + "/BadBrain/question.db", null);
```

Make sure the "BadBrain" directory exists, or you can create it!

Answer (score 1):

Please also check permission(android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) on manifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while running my app on JB devices. I was because they altered database path `/data/data/{package_name}/databases/`. To resolve use Android inbuilt API method as follows rather than hard coded path

```
mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and see like this.

```
SQLiteDataBase objDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASENAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

do you have the table android_meta data and locale set in your table?

Look at first steps here:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/